# Android newly added control by code is changed from original XML Control

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add spinner and `edittext` in my `android activity` on `button click` which looks like same as originally added in `xml file`. The `spinner` and `edittext` fields are adding properly upon `button click` on there right place.

**Controls added code in MainActivity.java**

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                productsIds++;
                LinearLayout lv = findViewById(R.id.lnear_layout);
                lv.addView(createLinearLayout());
            }
            public Spinner createProductSpinner() {
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.product_width)), Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.control_height)));
                final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
                spinner.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                spinner.setAdapter(productAdapter);
                return spinner;
            }
            public EditText createQuantityEditText() {
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.quantity_width)), Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.control_height)));
                final EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                editText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                editText.setHint("Quantity");
                return editText;
            }
            public Spinner createUnitSpinner() {
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.unit_width)), Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.control_height)));
                final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
                spinner.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                spinner.setAdapter(productAdapter);
                return spinner;
            }

            public LinearLayout createLinearLayout() {
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                final LinearLayout subLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                subLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                subLayout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                subLayout.addView(createProductSpinner());
                subLayout.addView(createQuantityEditText());
                subLayout.addView(createUnitSpinner());
                return subLayout;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: The question is when adding control programmatically (On Button Click) they looks different as compared to the original controls that are added in XML file.
Orientation is right but just the look is different.
I want to know how could i make similiar look for an EditText either added in XML file or either created in MainActivity class?